# What is the reason why USB plugs connect power before data

Tags: usb, connector

I am designing USB unplugging/plugging hardware and I wanted to know why USB plugs are designed such that the power leads make a connection before the data.  Is it purely to ensure that data is not able to connect at the same time and/or before the power is connected?

Because I'm not actually physically unplugging the connector, is the pin offset connection delay purely because of mechanical issues, or is it ok if they connect at the same time because there are no mechanical interactions happening with my hardware (it's all done through ICs/FETs).  My current version (without a delay) works, but I'm really wondering if it would be better (more in spec) were I to implement a delay when reconnecting power and data.

Comment: That design allows connection on run.

Comment: What is "connection on run"?

Comment: Ground connection allows plug to be connected while powered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually more extensive than that. The USB shield connection makes contact before any of the pins. After this the power pins connect, followed by the data pins.

The reason for this is that USB supports hot-plugging. This presents a number of issues to the electrical circuitry. The first is that there may be a large electrostatic potential on the device being connected and if this discharges, even through the power pins, it could damage both devices. This is why the shield connects first.

After this the power pins connect and this is done to ensure the device powers up first before voltage is presented at the data pins. Otherwise it is possible for current to leak back through the data pin input structure, which could damage the hardware and can cause unreliable startups.

If you are doing everything electrically then none of this is a problem and you should be fine to just connect everything at the same time.

Comment: So I never break the connector shield or the ground pin - the only connections I break are +5, d+, d-, and the differential pairs (USB3 connector) - from what you said it sounds like I'm good.

Comment: +1 for this, if you connect any data pin before ground, and after power, it will mess you up good, and most likely break things in a way that is difficult to debug and will make you sad for weeks. It can cause partial failures of components that come back and go away.

Comment: @Mike Unless you guarantee to connect the +5V line first, you can get a situation where there is a voltage on a data pin that is higher than the power supply voltage Vcc - as the power hasn't even been applied yet.  That can damage some devices.

Comment: So I currently use a TI USB 3.0 + USB2.0 Differential Switch (HD3SS6126) for data connections - I could add an IC to delay the logic signal such that the data lines switch over some amount of time later.  Right now they connect at the "same time" (I think the IC differential switch has something like a 70ps delay)

Answer (score 0):

Question-is there a definite minimum time requiredfrom power on to data on could this be implemented by adjusting (bending) the contacts of a relay?-an old fashioned solution, but hey-I'm nearly time-expired, like my bits box!

Comment: @user310550 Connecting USB using mechanical relays is not the worst thing, but I wouldn't do it that way. It's electrically very noisy. As the contacts ring, the low AC impedances on both sides of the cable ring very nicely with the wire and other parasitic inductances. It's almost a stress test. It's a bad idea to bend relay contacts to adjust anything. If the relay is worn out, replace it. To add delays, add series relays - perhaps faster ones for smaller delay increment. Many reed relays give you sub-ms propagation delays, for example.